# How to combine date from one column and time from another

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Currently I'm trying to select a datetime column from two date columns. I'm having the following situation:

1. `FROMDATE` column which contains dates without time, e.g. `08-01-2017 00:00:00`
2. `FROMTIME` column which contains times without a date, e.g. `01-01-1899 13:50:00`

Now I want to select both within one column, e.g. `SELECT (<what ever>) as FROMDATETIME ...`

> Expected result: 08-01-2017 13:50:00

But I'm not able to extract the date and time parts and add them together as a  `datetime`.

Spoken in a kind of *meta* sql: `select (date(FROMDATE) + time(FROMTIME)) as FROMDATETIME`.

I've tried a lot with `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` but was not able to get the expecting result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(t.fromdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') ||
               ' ' ||
               TO_CHAR(t.fromtime,'hh24:mi:ss'),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as full_date_col 
FROM YourTable t
```

Answer (score 4):

A way could be casting everything to char and then using the concatenatoin of values:

```
select to_date(to_char(FROMDATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy') || to_char(FROMTIME, 'hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd-mm-yyyyhh24:mi:ss')
from test
```

...but what I wanted to do (and I was unable to) is in Alex Poole's answer

Answer (score 3):

You could also use date arithmetic:

```
fromtime + (fromdate - trunc(fromtime))
```

The `fromdate - trunc(fromtime)` part gets the number of whole days between the nominal date in the 'time' column (with `trunc` to zero the time in that) and the actual date in the 'date' column. In your example that is 43106 days between 2017-01-08 and 1899-01-01. That number of days can then be added to the `fromtime`, which takes its date in 1899 up 43106 days to match the 2017 date.

Quick demo, using a CTE to generate the two example values, and showing the number of days between the dates as well as the result you want:

```
with t (fromdate, fromtime) as (
  select date '2017-01-08', cast (timestamp '1899-01-01 13:50:00' as date)
  from dual
)
select fromdate - trunc(fromtime) as days,
  fromtime + (fromdate - trunc(fromtime)) as fromdatetime,
  to_char(fromtime + (fromdate - trunc(fromtime)), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as formatted
from t;

      DAYS FROMDATETIME        FORMATTED          
---------- ------------------- -------------------
     43106 2017-01-08 13:50:00 08-01-2017 13:50:00
```

Comment: Please help me understand; is the "secret" in the parentheses, and then in the implicit casting it does when he finds the parentheses, right?

Comment: @Aleksej - I've updated with a bit more explanation. The bit in parentheses just gets the whole number of days - not really implicit casting, that's just what date arithmetic returns? That number added to the original time is also just normal date arithmetic. (The parentheses are there to make the subtraction happen first - otherwise you'd get data+date, which gets ORA-00975.)

Comment: Elegant solutions always seem so obvious when you understand them... May I do an upvote donation? :)

Answer (score 2):

If your `fromdate` and `fromtime` columns are DATE type, you can do the following:

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE(
      TO_CHAR(fromdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(fromtime, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
      'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
    ) AS fromdatetime
FROM my_table;
```

If your columns are VARCHAR, you have to do the following

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE(
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(fromdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(fromtime, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24:MI:SS'),
      'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
    ) AS fromdatetime
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @BendEg No problem ;)